# Could not see any options while installing amd catalyst via the .run installer

Tags: ati

I downloaded the catalyst .run file from the [Amd Website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) .

But when I try to install it, I could not see the installer options. It shows like a blank page.

Screenshot: [image: http://i.imgur.com/9m0r0.png?1]

Answer (score 1):

See the [ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI). On there are all the ways you can install it. Any problems let me know :)

Comment: Thank you. I have already visited that site. But still, I would like to know the cause of this issue.

Comment: Hi Ubuntu_amd-driver    Can you let us know what you did prior to getting to the screen if you could.Just a quick summary of any commands you did.                                                If it is stuck I would suggest you clean it up using the command                                        sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates to get back to normal then follow the answers already provided here on askubuntu                 http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200

Answer (score 1):

I really think you need to identify what card you are running and on what hardware and version of ubuntu. However for now I would strongly suggest cleaning out your installation

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

and then follow what I think is a really excellent guide here on this askubuntu site by 
XXXX

[Ask Ubuntu Guide to ATI installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

by Stephen Myall

Comment: I have Dell inspiron 15r 5520 model laptop with Ubuntu version 12.10 64 bit and Graphic card is AMD raedon 7670M DDR3 1GB graphic card. I tried that instruction, but still the same issue.

Comment: @ubuntu_amd-driver have you installed the drivers using the built-in tool on Ubuntu? Is there some reason you are using a non-standard method?

Comment: Yes. I installed with the built-in tool ( software sources--> additional drivers, I selected fglrx proprietary) , but then when I rebooted next time, I can't enter the desktop. So I went to recovery console and removed fglrx. Then only I was able to go to the desktop. Also, another reason is I need to have Catalyst control center.